# Imam used a device and plays a recorded translation of the khutbah

Tags: jumuah, technology, imam-al-jamaah

Today I witnessed something really new to me. After reciting his khutba in Turkish the imam (turkish mosque in Germany) came out with a device on which a record of translation of his sermon was recorded and played it, it felt strange but at least helped me to understand what the khutba was all about.

My question is are there any fatwas on this kind of use of technology?
What are the evidences to allow or prohibit using it?

One of my concerns is that the person who's voice we heard might not have been present at all in the mosque.

Comment: It might be not be truly relevant, but was the recording in Arabic or in German?

Comment: @Kilise In German maybe to avoid trouble with the German  authorities I guess and maybe also to reach the non Turkish audience.

Comment: Was the translation played in between the Turkish khutbah and the prayers? Or was it after the prayers were concluded?

Comment: @III-AK-III at what we may call the end of the first sermon.

Comment: @Medi1Saif, I think the issue here will be one of muwalah (continuity of both sermons), rather than of the use of the technology.

Comment: @III-AK-III I got used to sermon "breaks" here as often in the middle a different person stands up to give a summary or a full translation of the first khutba as German authorities request this and the audience usually includes people who don't speak the language of the Khateeb. So I don't consider this an issue at all. While the fact that a non present person is talking seems to me weird.

Comment: He already give khutba himself, so why it matter what he did after that?

Comment: @Harun it is an interruption of the khutba, many scholars consider a translation of the sermon by a different person as invalid or not permissible ... There are many issues in this